# Facebook API to get 'landmark' posts

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, get

How would I `GET` landmarks, like new job/ married/ moved, etc. from the facebook (or any other 3rd party) API??

I'm trying to make a timeline of 'big' moments using facebook, specifically on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/12400522/… that lets you use `FQL` instead of the `graph API` to send requests and then returns more exact information.

Facebook's `FQL` reference is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/